# sage page testing successful transaction not appearing in my sage page 'transactions' tab

Tags: transactions, opayo

I think this is pretty simple, But I haven't find the answer. I am implementing a sage page payment form and I am running the testing mode by now. So Everything seems to be working alright, when I place the order, user receive confirmation email and IS redirected properly and even the vendor receives a 'successful transaction' notification email.

BUT, when I log in to "My sage page" and click on the transactions tab, those transactions do not appear.

Is it because is testing? or is it a matter of time? (because actually I can see other transactions made in the same day through other implementation).

Do you have any idea of what could be causing this issue?

Kind regards,

Lily

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you are logging into Test My Sage Pay. The correct URL for this is: https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp

If you are still not able to see your test transaction then please email support@sagepay.com and provide us with your account details and we will take a look for you.

Kind Regards,

Neil

Comment: Thank you for you reply, that makes a lot of sense!!! I was in the live page. But I tried to log into the test link, but I couldn't log with the same user as in live, how do create a tester user?

Comment: Your Test and Live accounts are seperate. The users you create do not transfer from Test to Live or Live to Test. Log in as the Admin user (same on both Test and Live) entering the vendor name in the vendor and user name fields, then enter Admin password in password field. If you need the Admin password, contact 0845 111 4455 or email support@sagepay.com so we can send it to you.   Once logged into Settings within MySagePay click on Users> New User and create a user. Log out. Log in as new user, go to Transactions tab. You should see the transaction in there.